# Wordpress is asking me to re-install even though I had it installed

Tags: wordpress

All,
I wasn't paying attention and uploaded the wp-config.php to my wordpress site. I had it installed and it was working good but now everytime I go back to the site it's making me re-install Wordpress. How can I get my old wordpress site back again? I still see everything on in my database etc. I tried to re-update my table prefix but it doesn't work. How can I get it back? Please help!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: see also wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you do no have write access over the wp-config.php. Edit manually with the correct data (user, password, database) and it should work.

Also check .htaccess to have the correct form. Here is a default one:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to be working. Are there any other settings that I need to look at?

Comment: What version of WP were you using?

Comment: I got it back so that it shows my first page but when I login to my dashboard I see all my old pages but when I try and view one it says that the page can't be found. Any ideas why this would happen?